# How does a common gate MOSFET turn on if the gate is grounded?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, nmos, fet, common-gate

For a NMOS to turn on the Gate to Source potential diff has to be greater than the threshold voltage. But if the gate is grounded like shown in M1 below how could the MOSFET ever be turned ON (or how current could pass through)?

[image]

Comment: Include a schematic! NPN, OK, *Gate to Source potential diff* Why not call it \$Vgs\$ like everyone else here. Where did that MOSFET come from, you said NPN at the beginning. Why would you use a common gate? *how could the MOSFET ever be turned ON* It can't because **there's no schematic**.

Comment: Hint: the gate is grounded, but the source doesn't have to be.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, the following is copy and paste of my response (apologize for the sloppiness) 
Actually in the schematics, the source terminal of the NMOS is biased at ground, on which a small signal is added. So the only time the potential at the source will go negative is during the negative swing of the SMALL signal, which is apparently a very SMALL negative value. 
(I don't know how to attach a figure, but the schcematics is avalible on the 2nd page of the following link http://www.engr.usask.ca/classes/EE/221/notes/Chapter%205%20MOSFET_3.pdf  thankyou somuch

Comment: See Slide no. 24.

Comment: Please put the image of the schematic with the citation in the question, thanks

Answer (score 2):

An N channel MOSFET with a grounded gate requires a sufficient negative voltage at the source to turn on the MOSFET and conduct.

Comment: hi Andy, thank you for responding to my question. Actually in the schematics, the source terminal of the NMOS is biased at ground, on which a small signal is added. So the only time the potential at the source will go negative is during the negative swing of the SMALL signal, which is apparently a very SMALL negative value.

Answer (score 0):

Those shown on the diagram are small-signal values. The biasing is another subject, covered later in the printout.

[image]

There needs to be a power supply attached to Rd (rather than ground) and some means for biasing the transistor into active mode, which means Vgs > 0 for an enhancement-mode MOSFET (but could be Vgs = 0 for a depletion mode MOSFET eg. [BF1107](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/BF1107.pdf)).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I should keep on reading then hh. 

regards